# "Value for other visitors" as a criterion for good questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

### Original question

I have seen a number of questions on different Stack Exchange sites where it was suggested to close the question for various reasons.

One argument/criterion that I have never seen was "will this provide value to other readers"?

In my understanding, the main purpose of a Q/A site like this is to attract people who have a question in mind, and provide them with useful answers.

A question should contain the search terms for people with an equivalent problem, and the answer should address the expectations of visitors attracted by these search terms.

Solving the actual question author's specific problem is only a side effect, or a necessity to make this system work.

I wonder if the criterion of "value to other readers" can play a stronger role when deciding whether a question is relevant.

Some questions that were under threat of being closed for "opinion-based" or "asking for a tool" actually end up being upvoted a lot, and providing a lot of value for readers.

I suppose it is subjective, and maybe not suitable as a hard formal criterion by itself. But it seems, from my limited experience, that it should play a bigger role than it currently does.

Background: I spend most of my time on programming-related Stack Exchange sites. I also sometimes read the "Hot Network Questions," and see that other sites like Parenting (for example) produce valuable content despite the inevitable subjectivity.

### Notes for clarification

This is *not* a request to soften any specific rules about subjective or "shopping list" or any other type of questions.

The real goal was to discuss about the underlying goals when designing such rules.

The idea is to make "usefulness for readers" one (but not the only) criterion when designing rules for a stackexchange site.

It may very well be that the current system already IS the optimum in terms of usefulness, and we don't have to change anything. E.g. one could argue that subjective questions lead to answers that are not useful.

It is also possible that what I propose is already being done, and I simply missed it so far.

Now "useful" itself is a subjective term. So let's clarify.

Firstly, "useful" should always mean "useful within the intended scope of the respective stackexchange site."

The stackexchange network is useful to readers, if

- readers understand what to expect, and what not to expect, from the stackexchange network.
- readers with a question in mind find a (unique) sub-site and a (unique) answer within a (unique) Q/A thread, which sufficiently answers the question, or contains a hint which question should have been asked instead. This is implies that

  - scope and focus are important
  - duplicates are bad
  - findability is important
- there is a stream of clueless visitors that are being funneled to a place of illumination.
- Coverage: Most questions that *can* be answered effectively in a Q/A format are covered somewhere in the stackexchange network.

A stackexchange site is useful to readers, if

- readers understand what to expect and what not to expect to find on this specific site.
- readers that have questions within the scope of the site find either sufficient answers, or they learn which question to ask next.

A Q/A thread is useful to readers, if

- the question expressed in the thread is equivalent with the question the reader has in its mind.
- or if not, the reader will quickly understand that this is not what they were looking for.
- the answer addresses the points that the reader was looking for.
- readers leave with a better understanding of the subject.
- most of the useful information is at the top.

A question is useful to readers, if

- title and keywords attract readers with an equivalent question in mind, e.g. via web search or in-site search.
- the question leads to a useful Q/A thread.

Usefulness is not the same as popularity, as has been pointed out in some of the answers. But upvotes often indicate that many visitors are curious about the same question.

I imagine that all of these thoughts are already being considered implicitly. Maybe even explicitly somewhere. I just have never seen such arguments being made in everyday discussions about whether something is a good question. So I suspect that sometimes these goals are being lost.

This can lead to a situation where some curious visitors are left in a "dead end" where they find neither an answer, nor a constructive "ask something else" or "look somewhere else."

Comment: upvotes don't mean that the post was useful to the reader.  It's a rough *approximation* of that, but these highly opinion based questions are cases where we run headlong into that fact that these are approximations.  There are lots of posts that people *enjoy* and find *entertaining*, and end up upvoting as a result, even though they're not *useful*.  But anyway, there are hundreds of requests to allow opinion based questions; it's been discussed to death.  You should be reading over the previous discussions and really adding something new beyond, "I think we should allow these questions".

Comment: I meant "useful" in the sense that as a reader I have a better understanding of the subject after reading the question and the answers.

Comment: I am not really suggesting to change any specific rules or allow any specific type of questions that was previously not allowed. What I suggest, if anything, is to have "usefulness" or "educational value" as an implicit meta-goal to keep in mind when designing actual rules. Perhaps this is already being done, I simply had the impression so far that it is not. This is not a clear proposal, but rather a discussion.

Comment: @donquixote The questions that aren't allowed aren't allowed because they've been found to be not useful, not because they're useful and we're just mean.

Comment: @Servy I do not even disagree. I just think that sometimes this could be said more explicitly. This is the entire point of my largely misunderstood post. I hope my update clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this type of close reason is rare. Most of the time, the reason is something else, which includes being *too broad*. Too narrow of a question is really subjective and is rarely used due to that factor.

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for example has people review *specific* code belonging to the asker but the *answers* given provide lots of information and insight that can be useful to a much bigger audience. Sure some questions are of programs that are usually popular to make but that makes the narrow question into a question that becomes more visible to a much, much larger audience like the Internet.

Same goes for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Specific pieces of code, common problems in code isolated and brought up to a larger community of visitors.

Product recommendations are a different story here. In the right site with the right tag, you can ask a recommendation question. For example, you can ask site recommendations for posting appropriate questions here at Meta Stack Exchange. Product recommendations though can lead up to spam, debates, unfriendly competition, flame wars, <del>exploding unicorns</del>, and more undesirable things.

So... TL;DR, if a question is closed for being narrow, the question is probably really narrow or there is something else wrong with it. Product recommendations if posted on the wrong site and/or without the right tags can lead up to very undesirable results that will probably get ugly.